# Definition of $\left(\epsilon,\delta,\gamma\right)$-Random Differential Privacy

Tags: differential-privacy

$\left(\epsilon,\delta,\gamma\right)$-Random Differential Privacy as defined in [rubenstein17](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02562.pdf):

$$\begin{align*}Pr\left[\forall S \subset \mathbb{R}, Pr\left(A(D) \in S\right) \leq e^{\epsilon} \cdot Pr\left(A(D') \in S\right) + \delta\right] &\geq Pr\left[|f(D) - f(D')| \leq \Delta\right] \\ &\geq 1 - \gamma\end{align*}$$

$\Delta \text{is the global sensitivity}$

Why is this the following inequality true? Is there an intuitive explanation? 
My understanding is that the mechanism $A$ requires a bound on sensitivity for it to be $\left(\epsilon,\delta\right)$-DP.
$$Pr\left[\text{The mechanism } A \text{ satisfies } (\epsilon, \delta)\text{-DP}\right] \geq Pr\left(|f(D) - f(D')| \leq \Delta\right)$$